# DataBinding: How to create Recyclerview with multiple ViewHolder (multiple layout) using generics in Kotlin

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, kotlin, generics

I have the below code where I'am using generics in the RecyclerView with multiple ViewHolders, I'am trying to upgrade this code using DataBinding, I'am looking for a RecyclerView with multiple ViewHolders and use DataBinding in it.

```
class JumbledWordAdapter(
var items: List<JumbledWord>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

companion object {
    const val TYPE_PLACE_HOLDER = 0
    const val TYPE_ANSWER = 1
    const val INVALID = -1
}

var selectedItemPos = INVALID

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = (items[position].currentType)//choose layout type

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    return when (viewType) {
        TYPE_PLACE_HOLDER -> {
            PlaceHolderViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.lyt_jumbled_word_place_holder_item, parent, false)
            )
        }
        TYPE_ANSWER -> {
            AnswerViewHolder(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.lyt_jumbled_word_answer_item, parent, false)
            )
        }
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type")
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    when (holder) {
        is PlaceHolderViewHolder -> holder.bind(position)
        is AnswerViewHolder -> holder.bind(position)
    }
}

inner class PlaceHolderViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    private val cardParent: MaterialCardView = view.findViewById(R.id.cardParent)
    fun bind(position: Int) {
        cardParent.isSelected = items[position].isSelected
        cardParent.setOnClickListener {
           //some code.
        }
    }
}

inner class AnswerViewHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    private val cardParent: MaterialCardView = view.findViewById(R.id.cardParent)
    private val tvLetter: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tvLetter)
    fun bind(position: Int) {
        tvLetter.text = items[position].answer
        cardParent.setOnClickListener {
           //some code.
        }
    }
 }
}
```

Need to implement Databinding in this adapter class.

Answer (score 1):

I think DataBinding should be isolated in ViewHolder, because binding values to views is not the Adapter responsibility.

So I wrote this:

```
class JumbledWordAdapter(
    val items: List<ItemListFragment.JumbledWord>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    companion object {
        const val TYPE_PLACE_HOLDER = 0
        const val TYPE_ANSWER = 1
        const val INVALID = -1
    }

    var selectedItemPos = INVALID

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = (items[position].currentType)//choose layout type

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        return when (viewType) {
            TYPE_PLACE_HOLDER -> PlaceHolderViewHolder(parent)
            TYPE_ANSWER -> AnswerViewHolder(parent)
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Invalid view type")
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is PlaceHolderViewHolder -> holder.bind(position)
            is AnswerViewHolder -> holder.bind(position)
        }
    }

    inner class PlaceHolderViewHolder private constructor(
        val binding: LytJumbledWordPlaceHolderItemBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        constructor(parent: ViewGroup) : this(
            LytJumbledWordPlaceHolderItemBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )

        init {
            // set click listeners at view-holder initialize time
            binding.cardParent.setOnClickListener {
                if (adapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    //some code.    
                }
            }
        }

        fun bind(position: Int) {
            binding.cardParent.isSelected = items[position].isSelected
        }
    }

    inner class AnswerViewHolder private constructor(
        val binding: LytJumbledWordAnswerItemBinding
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        constructor(parent: ViewGroup) : this(
            LytJumbledWordAnswerItemBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                parent,
                false
            )
        )

        init {
            // set click listeners at view-holder initialize time
            binding.cardParent.setOnClickListener {
                if (adapterPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    //some code.    
                }
            }
        }

        fun bind(position: Int) {
            binding.tvLetter.text = items[position].answer
        }
    }
}
```

PS: Also we should set clickListeners in viewholder initialize time. (not in binding time)

Comment: adapterPosition  is deprecated. can I use getBindingAdapterPosition() ?

Comment: @Alfin I'm using the latest stable version of recyclerview (1.1.0). if you're using an unstable version, yes. you can use `getBindingAdapterPosition()` instead.